# Estou com problema na conexão de SQL com java

Tags: java, sql, banco-de-dados, eclipse, nullpointerexception

Bem... Fiz algumas classes, e chegou o momento de conectar para buscar um dado no banco; Ok. Ele já havia se conectado com o BD, porém, quando fiz a classe para buscar o dado, ele fica dando nullException, como se o banco não existisse.
Saquem:

```
public void executeSQL(String sql){
        try {
            stm = conn.createStatement(rs.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,rs.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
            rs = stm.executeQuery(sql);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro:" + e);
        }
    }
```

Aí eu busco assim:

```
csql.executeSQL("select * from usuarios");
```

então ocorre o erro (Mas é claro que instanciei);

Me ajudem, por favor.

Comment: Posta a stacktrace

Comment: Posta o Erro. Outra cooisa você não está fechando as conexões.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NPE signifique que alguma variável não está inicializada propriamente. Se você tivesse dito em qual linha era o problema ficaria mais fácil descobrir qual a referência inválida.

Se o erro está realmente no código acima (que obviamente está incompleto), eu diria que pode ser o seguinte:

1. `conn` não foi inicializado corretamente. Se `conn` é `null`, então `conn.createStatement` vai resultar num NPE.
2. `rs` é acessado antes da atribuição, por exemplo em `rs.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE`. Se `rs` é `null`, você vai ter um NPE mesmo que o atributo seja estático, por isso não é boa prática acessar constantes estáticas em variáveis. Troque por `ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE`.